# Understanding the notation of Ring problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The question is Let $R$ be an integral domain, and let $u \in R*$. Show that $u$ divides every non-zero element of R.

I am confused of what $R*$ is in this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It’s $R^*$, I suspect, and judging from what you’re being asked to prove, it’s probably the set of units (i.e., invertible elements) of $R$.

Comment: (In fact the set $R^*$ of units is the largest possible subset of $R$ for which that statement is true.)